# Kendo grid - Posted Edit is null at Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using kendo grid with Popup edit.  I verified the data is posted from the view (I can see it in the Network Tab, here is a look at it:

```
{"LetterId":12,"BodyText":"This is a test","CreatedDate":"07/31/2013","CreatedBy":"Grace Rodgers","ModifiedDate":"07/31/2013","ModifiedBy":"Grace Rodgers","PersonId":18,"FirstName":"Jason","LastName":"Bigby"}:
```

However, I have a breakpoint at the json method in the controller, and when hovering over the model parameter, in shows all fields are null.  Here is the first couple lines of the controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult JsonEditLetter(LetterViewModel model)
    {
```

and the kendo code in the view:

```
var PersId = $("#PersonId").val();

    var ds_LettersGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetLetterList", "Letter")/' + PersId,
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            update: {
                url: '@Url.Action("JsonEditLetter", "Letter")',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                if (type == "update") {

                    data.models[0].CreatedDate = kendo.toString(new Date(data.models[0].CreatedDate), "MM/dd/yyyy");
                    data.models[0].ModifiedDate = kendo.toString(new Date(data.models[0].ModifiedDate), "MM/dd/yyyy");

              return kendo.stringify(data.models[0]);
                }
            },

        },
        batch: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "LetterId",
                fields: {
                    BodyText: { editable: true },
                    CreatedDate: { editable: false, type: "date"}, 
                    ModifiedDate: { editable: false, type: "date" },
                    CreatedBy: { editable: false},
                    ModifiedBy: { editable: false },
                    PersonId: { defaultValue: PersId }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#letter-list").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds_LettersGrid,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: { extra: false, operators: {
                string: { startswith: "Starts with", eq: "Is equal to" }
            }
            },
            pageable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "BodyText", title: "Letter Content", width: 400, filterable: false
            }, {
                field: "CreatedBy", title: "Author", filterable: false
            }, {
                field: "CreatedDate", title: "Original Date", format: "{0:g}", filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker" }
            }, {
                field: "ModifiedBy", title: "Edited By", filterable: false
            }, {
                field: "ModifiedDate", title: "Editted On", format: "{0:g}", filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker" }
            }, {
                command: [ "edit" ], title: "", width: "110px"
            }],
            height: "300px",
            resizable: true,
            editable: "popup"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add default value to your id field , becouse the client side generates new id value, what you already have in server autoincrement generated id value and its shooting error

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: "LetterId",
                fields: {
                    LetterId: {defaultValue: 16000}
                    BodyText: { editable: true },
                    CreatedDate: { editable: false, type: "date"}, 
                    ModifiedDate: { editable: false, type: "date" },
                    CreatedBy: { editable: false},
                    ModifiedBy: { editable: false },
                    PersonId: { defaultValue: PersId }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that made no difference.

Comment: Oh wait !Try change id to LetterId

Comment: I modified answear, try again

Comment: Sorry, still null.  Should i put something other than 16000?

Comment: Nope , just try to use simple kendo grid in razor mode. Or just send a test data with couple fields

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it wanted a specific content type.  The type being passed was a form, but the controller wanted json.  So the Transport now looks like:

```
            update: {
                url: '@Url.Action("JsonEditLetter", "Letter")',
                dataType: 'json',
     >>>>>>>>   contentType: "application/json",
                type: "POST"
            },
```